# Powershell Basic

Tags: powershell, calculator

I have to do a simple calculator `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` on PowerShell for my coding introduction course. Why my Variable `Valeur1` & `Valeur2` don't remain intact during the integer validation ? My 4 options give a random answer and don't remember the initial value of my 2 `Read-Host` Variables.

```
Write-Host "Microsoft Powershell Calculator "

$R = $True
$OK = $True

while ($R -eq $True) {
    do {
        $Valeur1 = [int]::TryParse((Read-Host "Entrez une premiere valeur numerique"), [ref]$OK)
        if (-not $OK) {
            Write-Host ("ERREUR ! Vous devez entrez une valeur numerique")
            $OK = $false
        }
        else{
            $OK = $true    
        }
    } while (-not $OK)

    do {
        $Valeur2 = [int]::TryParse((Read-Host "Entrez une seconde valeur numerique"), [ref]$OK)
        if (-not $OK) {
            Write-Host ("ERREUR ! Vous devez entrez une valeur numerique")
            $OK = $false
        }
        else{
            $OK = $true    
        }
    } while (-not $OK)

    $operation = Read-Host -prompt "Quelle opération voulez-vous réaliser? Choisissez entre [+, -, *, or /] "
    Switch($operation)
    {
        -
        {
            Write-Host("Le resultat de votre soustraction est :")
            $Valeur1 - $Valeur2
        }
        +
        {
            Write-Host("Le resultat de votre addition est :")
            $Valeur1 + $Valeur2
        }
        *
        {
            Write-Host("Le resultat de votre multiplication est :")
            $Valeur1 * $Valeur2
        }
        /
        {
            Write-Host("Le resultat de votre division est :")
            $Valeur1 / $Valeur2
        }
        default
        {
            Write-Host("Option Invalide")
        }
    }

    $choix = Read-Host "Desirez-vous continuer? Y/N" 
    if($choix -eq "Yes"){
        $R = $true
    }
    if($choix -eq "Y"){
        $R = $true
    }
    else{
        $R = $false
        exit
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`Int32.TryParse(String, Int32)` Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0):

> `result` **Int32**
> When this method returns, contains the 32-bit signed integer value equivalent of the number contained in `s`, if the conversion succeeded, or zero if the conversion failed.

When you do `[ref]$OK`, if the conversion succeeds, this variable will hold the ***parsed*** result of your `.TryParse` operation, but, you're overwriting this value on your `if` and `else` conditions (`$OK = $true`  and `$OK = $false`).

Furthermore, the output from the `.TryParse` method will be `$true` / `$false` depending on the success of the operation (**this boolean will be assigned to `$valeur1` and `$valeur2`** since both variables have assigned this operation).

> **Returns** `Boolean`
> `true` if `s` was converted successfully; otherwise, `false`.

Here is a simplified, *working*, variation of your code. It's worth mentioning that, since you're performing 2 parse operations, a [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2) (`ParseInput`) holding the same logic would make more sense so that the code is not repeated.

```
Write-Host "Microsoft Powershell Calculator V3"

function ParseInput {
    $ref = ''
    do {
        $parsed = [int]::TryParse((Read-Host "Entrez une premiere valeur numerique"), [ref]$ref)
        if (-not $parsed) {
            Write-Host "ERREUR ! Vous devez entrez une valeur numerique"
        }
    } while (-not $parsed)
    $ref
}

$R = $true

while ($R) {
    $Valeur1 = ParseInput
    $Valeur2 = ParseInput
    $operation = Read-Host "Quelle opération voulez-vous réaliser? Choisissez entre [+, -, *, or /] "
    Switch($operation) {
        - {
            Write-Host "Le resultat de votre soustraction est :"
            $Valeur1 - $Valeur2
        }
        + {
            Write-Host "Le resultat de votre addition est :"
            $Valeur1 + $Valeur2
        }
        * {
            Write-Host "Le resultat de votre multiplication est :"
            $Valeur1 * $Valeur2
        }
        / {
            Write-Host "Le resultat de votre division est :"
            $Valeur1 / $Valeur2
        }
        default {
            Write-Host "Option Invalide"
        }
    }
    $choix = Read-Host "Desirez-vous continuer? Y/N"
    if($choix -notmatch "^(Yes|Y)$") {
        $R = $false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Santiago your logical vision of my rag is extremely clear.

Comment: @G0Y1M my pleasure, if something was not clear enough do let me know and i'll try to explain it better

Comment: The only thing that you add to this small script that I cant understand is $ref how is it affect the script and in second place how did powershell transcript parse input into an array that can be exhange for each of my variable

Comment: @G0Y1M `$ref` must be there because, in order to `.TryParse` something, the variable __must exists / must be defined__ prior performing the operation, tho, `$ref = ''` can just be anything as long as it's defined (it could be `$ref = $null` or `$ref = 1`, doesn't matter). As for `ParseInput`, that's not an array, it's a function that will return the parsed integer when succeed.

Comment: @G0Y1M btw, `$ref` as a variable name can be just anything too, just that I named it `$ref` so that someone reading the code has an easier time understanding what it is and why it's there.

Comment: Oh wow, my last comment was a clear overview of my basic knowledge of programming language. So it is in fact not an array and when the shell read the script he call the function that you made for TryParse at each variable line witch in this case is only 2. Valeur1 & Valeur2. What a great opportunity to exchange about basics with a resourceful person like you

Comment: @G0Y1M that's correct, you got it perfectly :) I added a link to my answer to the `about_Functions` doc which will get you on track to begin your journey. If the answer was helpful, please consider accepting it